# Laravel - Verified middleware is rejecting verified users

Tags: php, laravel, middleware, verification

So I have this problem where a user will successfully verify his/her email, but then when they enter a route with the "verified" middleware, they will be rejected?

Protected Route:

```
Route::get('/venue/{venue}', 'profileController@index')->name('profile.show')->middleware('verified');
```

Ensure email is verified class:

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next, $redirectToRoute = null)
{
    if (! $request->user() ||
        ($request->user() instanceof MustVerifyEmail &&
        ! $request->user()->hasVerifiedEmail())) {
        return $request->expectsJson()
                ? abort(403, 'Your email address is not verified.')
                : Redirect::route($redirectToRoute ?: 'verification.notice');
    }
    return $next($request);
}
```

If I call `hasVerifiedEmail()` on the user, it returns true. 
Any help would be fantastic!

Comment: What do you mean by rejected? do you get `403, 'Your email address is not verified.'`

Comment: I get a redirect back to the previous page

Comment: Try accessing the URL with Postman or Javascript to see the response

Comment: The middleware should redirect to `email/verify` and not to previous page

Answer (score 0):

You may be redirecting verified users to a page that only non-verified users can see, which ends up just redirecting them back to the previous page/home page(depending on how you have it set up).